# Can't throw exception in the graphql @BatchMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-graphql

I'm using `Spring` with `graphql` and have the following code:

```
@QueryMapping
public Client clientById(Long id) {
    return dao.findById(id).orElse(null);
}

@BatchMapping(typeName = "Client")
public List<Optional<LegalEntity>> legalEntity(List<Client> clients) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet");
}
```

I got an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected return value: MonoError
at org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.support.BatchLoaderHandlerMethod.toFlux(BatchLoaderHandlerMethod.java:196) ~[spring-graphql-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
at org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.support.BatchLoaderHandlerMethod.invokeForIterable(BatchLoaderHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-graphql-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
....
```

Seems like library wraps the exceptions into `Mono.error(..)`, returns it and than can't resolve that type. As a result, my exception handlers don't work and there's no way I can intercept original error. If I change return type to `Flux<Optional<LegalEntity>>` and return `Flux.error` it works. But is it possible to handle errors returning lists?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, you could handle errors returning lists if you change your `@BatchMapping` return type to `Mono<List<Optional<LegalEntity>>>`, that is:

```
@BatchMapping(typeName = "Client")
public Mono<List<Optional<LegalEntity>>> legalEntity(List<Client> clients) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet");
}
```

Hope it helps!